# Заменить адресную строку

Tags: .htaccess, php

Всем привет! Есть сайт, у него такая адресная строка `http://setka.kz/index.php?view=cat&id=setka_rabica_ocinkovannaya` как сделать `http://setka.kz/cat/setka_rabica_ocinkovannaya.html`?

Пишу в `htacess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?view=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

не работает, эту ссылку взял на сайте: [Mod Rewrite Generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/)

Comment: Почитайте статейку - "[Самый простой и логичный ЧПУ для PHP](http://epsiloncool.ru/php/samyj-prostoj-i-logichnyj-chpu-dlya-php)". Возможно, что пересмотрите своё отношение к ЧПУ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, вы неверно указали регулярное выражение. REQUEST_URI, если мне не изменяет память, всегда начинается с "/". Попробуйте исправить вот так:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?view=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Cтранно не работает,(((( может потому что проверяю на локальном сервере через apache?

Comment: Никогда. **Никогда** не проверяйте на локалке настройки .htaccess! Ибо не дождетесь их действия.  

Comment: интересно, что вы имели ввиду под "не дождетесь их действия"?

Comment: то, что работать не будут.

Comment: с чего бы?

Comment: личный опыт (может быть и я не прав, опираясь на него), но на локалку все было плохо

Comment: @Arc, это частный случай, вызванный настройками сервера. Может вам поможет эта [информация](http://i-vd.org.ru/articles/config_htaccess.shtml)

Comment: Возможно, дело в флаге. Поставьте вместо [L] выражение [L,QSA]